# "Extra argument 'complete' in call" when passing Swift closure

Tags: swift

I've extended the animation functions on UIView to add some shortcut functions for scaling as seen below.

```
extension UIView {
    class func animatePressed(viewToAnimate: UIView, complete: ((Bool) -> Void)) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.20, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.allZeros, animations: {
            viewToAnimate.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(viewToAnimate.transform, scale, scale)
        }, completion: complete)
    }
}
```

The issue occurs when I attempt to call this function. Since I only care about when the animation finishes, I am using the '_' symbol as a parameter placeholder.

```
UIView.animatePressed(messagesImage, complete: { _ in
    self.delegate.newSubViewControllerRequested(UIStoryboard.messageListViewController()!)
})
```

I receive the following compiler error...

```
Extra argument 'complete' in call
```

If I change the code to either of the following, the compiler stops complaining.

```
UIView.animatePressed(messagesImage, complete: { _ in
    if 1 == 1 {
        self.delegate.newSubViewControllerRequested(UIStoryboard.messageListViewController()!)
    }
})

UIView.animatePressed(messagesImage, complete: { _ in
    self.delegate.newSubViewControllerRequested(UIStoryboard.messageListViewController()!)
    return
})
```

Is this a bug in Swift or am I totally missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. It's not a Swift bug, and you're not missing anything - because in fact you've solved the problem correctly!

The issue is that, as a shortcut, if an anonymous function consists of *just one line*, Swift tries to use that as the return value. That return value, however, is invalid for a `(Bool) -> Void`.

In other words, when you say this:

```
UIView.animatePressed(messagesImage, complete: { _ in
    self.delegate.newSubViewControllerRequested(UIStoryboard.messageListViewController()!)
})
```

It is exactly as if you had said this:

```
UIView.animatePressed(messagesImage, complete: { _ in
    return self.delegate.newSubViewControllerRequested(UIStoryboard.messageListViewController()!)
})
```

But you can't say that, because your `newSubViewControllerRequested` returns an actual non-Void value. So now you've got a type mismatch; this anonymous function doesn't fit the required signature.

So the workaround is just what you did - add more lines to the anonymous function (to suppress the shortcut), and/or provide an explicit void return value.

Comment: Ah! Makes sense now! I now remember the auto-returning functionality in a turtorial I watched. Handy when writing filtering closures, but not so much in this case. :P

"Another possibility is to declare the void return value explicitly in your in line." What do you mean by this exactly?

Comment: That part is wrong. :( I'll delete it from my answer.